# the usage message for a function does not display on Mathematica 10.3.1 Linux

Tags: usage-messages

I write a function

```
f[x_]:=Module[{},(
f::usage="gives the square of x"
x^2
)]
```

When I run `?f` I get a this output:

```
Global`
CreateUUID["Info-"]
False
False
False
```

What is the problem? Is it a bug in mathematica ?

Comment: Try `RebuildPacletData[]` and then restart Mathematica.

Comment: @ilian, doing that I get this error "Cannot open \!\(\"CloudObjectLoader`\"\). "

Comment: Then a better idea would be to close Mathematica and delete the `~/.Mathematica/Paclets` directory.

Comment: @ilian, Could you explain why? I can not delete any thing. I have not permissions.

Comment: @ilian, I have already detect a lot of bug's in mathematica, So I am not sure that it is a problem of configuration. It may another bug!

Comment: It is a bug. What I suggested is a workaround. Are you sure you don't have permissions, this location should be inside your own home directory...

Comment: @ilian, I found the folder. Could give me what does it do this file?